# Setting up portforwarding for server behind NAT

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, nat

With one of those "consumer VPN" like [Privateinternetaccess, that have portforwarding](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/blog/the-beginners-guide-to-vpn-port-forwarding/) is it possible to do the following:

Set up a server on a network behind a NAT and use portforwarding so that the server can be accessed over the internet? Also in the VPN client interface, I'm confused by the settings: remote port and local port. For example if the server is running on port 8090, would that go as the local port or remote port? Which port would someone trying to connect to the server enter?

Portforwarding does not address the issue of connecting to a server behind a non-static IP address, correct?

Comment: you write "a non-static IP address" <-- that would be called a dynamic IP address

Comment: According to my research, To set up port forwarding, you must assign specific ports or a range of ports to a specific IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also in the VPN client interface, I'm confused by the settings: remote port and local port. For example if the server is running on port 8090, would that go as the local port or remote port? Which port would someone trying to connect to the server enter?

In most interfaces, both labels usually mean destination ports, but "remote port" is the external one (entered by users), while "local port" is internal (seen by your own server). They can be identical, or they can be different, depending on your needs.

So if you enter **123** as 'remote' and **80** as 'local', then users connecting to **<VPN_public_IP>:123** will end up being forwarded to **<your_computer>:80**. Basically the same as you would find in home routers.

(This meaning of 'remote port' is, unfortunately, completely different from what it means within TCP itself – as TCP packets have destination *and* source ports.)

> Portforwarding does not address the issue of connecting to a server behind a non-static IP address, correct?

It doesn't. But if a VPN product specifically offers port-forwarding, then I would kind of expect it to offer a static IP address as well.